# How to return `this` in the generic class?

Tags: java, generics

For example, I have a some class:

```
public class Test<T> {
    public T setField() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Of course, it's an incorrect class. But can I write it some else? (to it hasn't errors).
P.S. I know that I can write an abstract method to override it in the child class. But I ask about the generic class only (in the its class body only).

Comment: How can an instance of `Test` be an instance of `T`? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to it return the class instance in the child class. When I'll create class `class ChildTest extends Test<ChildTest>`. Just I need to use the builder pattern and move some methods in the parent class. Maybe it has another ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting this to `T` makes only sense if you use a recursive type bound. Still you need to add a cast and suppress the warning:

```
abstract class Test<T extends Test<T>> {
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public T setField()
     {
         return (T)this;
     }
}
```

Define derived classes like:

```
public class DerivedTest extends Test<DerivedTest> { ... }
```

and now this works without any casts needed in the client code:

```
DerivedTest d = new DerivedTest().setField();
```

Comment: Thank you! It's that I sought!

Comment: But this is unsafe.

Comment: @newacct why is this unsafe?

Comment: @wero: The cast is unsafe. `this` may not be a `T`.

Comment: @newacct only possible if one screws up the extends clause of the derived class. A manageable risk in my eyes.

Comment: @wero: I'm not sure what you mean by "screws up"; a programmer should be able to define classes according to the declared bounds and it should be safe. If you are going to rely on the programmer to follow some unenforced convention, that is not type safety. Also, you wouldn't need the bounds and can just declare it as `abstract class Test<T>` because, since you are assuming the programmer does it your way anyway, it should make no difference.

Comment: @newacct the recursive type bound is a way to signal to any user of the base class that `T` is expected to be derived from the base. If you think that this is not better than plain `T` then I guess we have fundamental different views about class design. In the end my mistake to enter a discussion about supposedly unsafe casts without letting you prove first that you never write unsafe casts.

Comment: @wero: "the recursive type bound is a way to signal to any user of the base class that T is expected to be derived from the base" I agree. That's what the bound says. But, nothing in your code actually relies upon the fact that `T` is derived from the base at all. In particular, no matter if you have that bound or not, either way it does not guarantee that `this` is a `T`. "about supposedly unsafe casts without letting you prove first that you never write unsafe casts." It is okay to write unchecked casts that are provably safe. Here, your casts are provably unsafe.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to return an instance of your class (`this`), it does simply by using the class declaration (`Test<T>`):

```
public Test<T> setField() {
    return this;
}
```

If you want to return a type of a generic parameter, look at [@wero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215527/wero)'s answer.

Comment: Is it return the child instance? Or the generic parent class instance?

Comment: Sorry, I badly understand this mechanism.

Comment: There are no "child" or "generic parent" classes. There is only a `Test` class. Google for "java generics type erasure".

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for something like this to work safely in general in Java. `this` is only known to be an instance of `Test<T>`, which is not known to be a subtype of `T`, the type you want to return. There is no bound on `T` that can guarantee that `this` is an instance of `T`. No matter what bounds you give `T`, for any type that you can use for `T` that satisfies those bounds (call it `X`), I can just define a new class (unrelated to `X`) that extends `Test<X>`, and you cannot return an instance of this class as `X`, because it is not an `X`.